# How to count the number of triplets found in a string?

Tags: python, string

string1 = "abbbcccd"
string2 = "abbbbdccc"

How do I find the number of triplets found in a string. Triplet meaning a character that appears 3 times in a row. Triplets can also overlap for example in string 2 (abbbbdccc)

The output should be:

```
2 < -- string 1
3 <-- string 2
```

Im new to python and stack overflow so any help or advice in question writing would be much appreciated.

Comment: You will need to count the occurrence of every character and use `ceil` function to find the total count

Comment: You are normally expected to show some attempt to solve it,  i.e. "here's my code but it didn't work because X"  see : How To Ask:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try iterating through the string with a `while` loop, and comparing if the character and the two other characters in front of that character are the same. This works for overlap as well.

```
string1 = "abbbcccd"
string2 = "abbbbdccc"
string3 = "abbbbddddddccc"

def triplet_count(string):
    it = 0    # iterator of string
    cnt = 0   # count of number of triplets
    while it < len(string) - 2:
        if string[it] == string[it + 1] == string[it + 2]:
            cnt += 1
        it += 1
    return cnt

print(triplet_count(string1)) # returns 2
print(triplet_count(string2)) # returns 3
print(triplet_count(string3)) # returns 7
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple script should work...

```
my_string = "aaabbcccddddd"

# Some required variables
old_char = None
two_in_a_row = False
triplet_count = 0

# Iterates through characters of a given string
for char in my_string:
    # Checks if previous character matches current character
    if old_char == char:
        # Checks if there already has been two in a row (and hence now a triplet)
        if two_in_a_row:
            triplet_count += 1
        two_in_a_row = True
    # Resets the two_in_a_row boolean variable if there's a non-match.
    else:
        two_in_a_row = False
    old_char = char

print(triplet_count) # prints 5 for the example my_string I've given
```